# JQuery Ajax Error Text

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, response

I would like to set the error message on Ajax error operation from Java Servlet.

```
request.setAttribute(BreezeWebConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE, errMsg);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("Move Ticket Error - " + textStatus);
console.log("Move Unknown Ticket Error");
}
```

The textStatus is predefined in Jquery but i need to set custom error message in java servlet and retrieve it on this error function. How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: i guess you have to add a if condition that with the `textStatus` to check for that predefined error message and set your own custom message

Comment: Did you try `errorThrown`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write the error message to the response body as plain text or XML or JSON.

Here's an example assuming plain text:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(errMsg);
```

You can extract it as follows:

```
var message = jqXHR.responseText;
```

Note that jQuery has builtin XML and JSON parsing as well, so it'd be easy like that as well.

Comment: Could you pls tell the type of response object?

Comment: @jenius: Uh. Question is about servlets.

Comment: Is It HttpServletResponse  in java ? cause I have the same problem, and nothing helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get the correct error like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Move Ticket Error - Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Move Unknown Ticket Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Just make an ajax call. In case of any error, you will get the alert.